# Cannot use subprocess.call with psexec.exe

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess, psexec

I'm trying to use psexec to run a script on remote PCs but when I use subprocess.call I get `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

I have downloaded PsExec, unzipped and put all contents from the download in

`C:\Windows\System32\` and my test code is:

```
from subprocess import call

call(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\PsExec.exe'])
```

I just wanted to see if i could see the command working, but no luck.

When I  try `call(['C:\\Windows\\System32\\PsExec.exe'], shell=True)` I get

`'C:\Windows\System32\PsExec.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

When I try another propgram in that folder it seems to work... Is there something I'm immediatly missing?

Comment: "System32" is redirected to "SysWOW64" in a 32-bit process. In Windows 7+ you can access the real "System32" as "SysNative".

Comment: Oh thanks, I literally only just got round it by re-installing it at C:\PsTools anyway, but thanks for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
from subprocess import call

call(['C:\\Windows\\SysNative\\PsExec.exe'],shell=True)
```

i hope it's work on your system!